# Can I install a previous version of a plugin using the cordova plugin add command?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I am trying to rebuild a cordova project from scratch and creating documentation along the way. I would like to be able to install consistent versions of plugins to avoid having to retest new code for the time being. Is there a way to specify a previous version of a plugin similar to the way you can specify a previous version of cordova? For example, I am familiar with the following syntax to install a specific version of cordova:

```
npm install -g cordova@3.1
```

And I'm able to install a plugin with the following syntax:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

I would like to be able to so something like the following:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device@2.1
```

Any insight including "not possible" would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

from official cordova website

http://cordova.apache.org/news/2013/10/21/cordova-registry.html

From anywhere within an app’s directory, plugins can be added to a project with

```
cordova plugin add [PLUGIN_ID]
```

where PLUGIN_ID is the id (typically reverse-domain style) shown on the plugin registry website. You can also download a specific version of a plugin:

```
cordova plugin add [PLUGIN_ID]@[VERSION]
```

Comment: which is basically what you have, so not sure if you already tried that command

Comment: Yes, I actually tried that command using several different version number formats (for example, when installing Cordova 3.1 using '@3.1' works but '@3.1.0' doesn't) so I tried a few different formats with the device plugin ('@0.2.1', '@2.1', etc.) so maybe there is just an issue with the registry. But thank you for the link to the documentation. I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Found that the command works fine, it was just that 0.2.2 is the oldest version of the device plugin in the registry.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem with a plugin. This is how it worked for me:

Usually I would have added the plugin like this

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts
```

Instead I fetched the plugin from github like this (note the version tag at the end)

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#1.1.0
```

Comment: For my specific issue it was not the plugin's fault, the solution was installing a different cordova iOS version. I went from 4.0.1(bad) to 4.1.0 (good) then finally to 3.9.2 because of iOS6,7 support.

Answer (score 1):

First is First we need to remove currently installed version plugin

```
cordova plugin remove <plugin-name>@<version>
```

then install required plugin

```
cordova plugin add <plugin-name>@<version>
```