# How to install phonegap-plugin-push in IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, sencha-touch, cordova-plugins

I am new in IOS push notification, I try to install phonegap-plugin-push in my IOS app but it send error "required sender id". I am little bit confuse that in sender ID what I put there.

Platform: IOS
Cordova CLI version: 5.1.1
cordova plugin version | grep phonegap-plugin-push :1.7.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following command

cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="12345"

It worked for me on iOS.Hope it helps :)

Comment: What if I want a specific version of plugin-push? like 1.11.1

Comment: @ShishirShetty try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391431/can-i-install-a-previous-version-of-a-plugin-using-the-cordova-plugin-add-comman